# Replace Raspbian by Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, system-installation, raspberry-pi

I am currently running Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi. I would like to change distribution to Arch Linux ARM. Is it possible, from Raspbian, to create a new partition and install Arch on it? If so, how?

Once this has been done, how can I then delete the Raspbian partition?

Comment: Is it because you have no laptop or PC that you want to create a new partition, not just backup the data and copy the new system on top of the old one?

Comment: The end goal is to have Raspbian completely uninstalled, and Arch Linux ARM running. I assumed that this would require first installing Arch on a new partition, but I am happy to follow whatever the best way to achieve this would be. I have a Macbook, and am logged into the Pi via SSH. The reason that I did not just install it from the Macbook is because the installation steps on the following page cannot be carried out from a Mac: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2

Comment: But do you *need* to do this on Raspberry? Or do you have a laptop or a PC that can help you?

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us your hardware configuration.  The Raspberry can only boot from the SD card as far as I am aware, and it has only one SD card slot.  It may be possible to overwrite the current OS by being extremely careful and placing all needed things in a ramfs, but that is completely unneeded in this case.  And it is very dangerous to try to overwrite the current OS since, if you do something wrong or forget about something, there's no way to fix it.  Are you really installing Arch on the SD card from which the Pi booted?

Comment: My options are either to do this on my Macbook (but I cannot follow the steps in the above link on a Mac) and therefore don't know how else I could? I'm therefore assuming I can only do this on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install Arch on the SD card from which the Pi booted.

Comment: Seriously, do not try to re-partition a disk from where your OS is running.  At best you can buy a SD-to-USB converter and then do it on a separate SD card.  Finally, what are your problems on OSX?  The only command there that is not trivial is `bsdtar` which is simply `tar` with BSD parameters, which turns out to the the default `tar` on OSX. (also, use the @ calls, e.g. @Russel, to get people's attention, makes things easier to search :) )

Comment: You need to format and partitioning the sd card using a linux os first , try this guide https://github.com/phortx/Raspberry-Pi-Setup-Guide

Comment: I couldn't even use wget command from OSX. If you know how to adapt the commands in the guide so that I can be executed from a Mac that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Noobs has Arch.

Follow the Noobs Setup video on [this site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/videos/).

It will tell you how to install it from Mac.

Here's the [download site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/).

Comment: Sadly my version of Noobs did not come with Arch - I was expecting that it would but Raspbian was my only option.

Comment: Get the one they have on that site.

Comment: They show the selection of systems in that video at 3'10''.